# shopping cart session variables do not update or unset

Tags: php, session-variables, shopping-cart

I'm creating a shopping cart. Two problems with the add and remove item features. When adding an item that's already in the cart, it doesn't overwrite the existing one, leading to two instances of the same item in the cart.
Removing items only works for the topmost item on the  list.

Ive debugged my code and realized the add problem is in the switch case, probably where it identifies whether the item exists in the cart

Hopefully this code is concise enough

```
    switch($_GET["action"])
    {
        case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) 
        {
            $id=$_POST["id"];
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE itemid='$id'");
            while($itembyId=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $itemArray = array($id=>array('name'=>$_POST["name"],
                 'id'=>$id, 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'details'=>$_POST["details"],
                  'price'=>$_POST["price"]));

                if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
                {
                    if(in_array($itembyId["itemid"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) 
                    {
                        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
                        {   
                                if($itembyId["itemid"] == $k)
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case "remove":
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
             {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
                 {
                        if($_GET["id"] == $k)
                            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                            unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you please boil the code down to the necessary part? This is utterly verbose and confusing.

Comment: You need to learn to debug, so you can come to Stack Overflow with a **specific** problem instead of posting all your code and asking us to debug it. Try to isolate the point in your code where it's behaving incorrectly, and put some more echo statements in until you find which values are different than you expected.

Comment: Changed the code, only included the important part. I hope this is more useful